# populating db records in a common NIB(Because same UI but different data from sqlite ) depending upon button clickd

Tags: iphone

i have followed [this tutorial](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/) 
i am working on a simple game project.I am having a view consisting of uibutton.for eg,
Movies Button, Places Button and Personalities Button.
Now on clicking on Movies button a new NIB opens.Similarly for clicking on Places and for Personalities buttons the same NIB opens.

**Note:NIB is same for all three buttons Movies,Places and Personalities,but data to be populated on that NIB is different.**

i have done some stuff regarding connecting to database through resources and adding framework.Holding info(for Movies,Places and Personalities) in corresponding arrays in appdelegate.
I have used NSObject class(Questions.h and .m) having id and name for question Movies,Places and Personalities.I had initialize them.

**Problem**:i want to open a single nib class/file having different instance(same UI but diffenet data depending on type of button pressed Movies,Places and Personalities).Some of the code snippts for my approach:

#### my appdelegate.h

```
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;

    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString *databasePath;
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Array to store the Movies objects
    NSMutableArray *movies;
    // Array to store the places objects
    NSMutableArray *places;
    // Array to store the personalities objects
    NSMutableArray *personalities; }  
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *movies;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *places;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *personalities;
```

#### My appdelegate.m

```
-(void) readMoviesFromDatabase   
{   
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from tblMovies";  
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;  
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)   
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)   
            {                               
                NSString *amovieName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];  
                NSInteger amovieId = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 2);              
                Questions *questions = [[Questions alloc] initWithmovieName:amovieName movieId:amovieId];               
                [movies addObject:questions];  
                [questions release];  
            }  
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);  
        }
        [self closeDataBase];  
}
```

Similarly for:
`-(void) readPlacesFromDatabase and (void) readPersonalitiesFromDatabase`

#### My Question.m file:

```
-(id)initWithmovieName:(NSString *)mN movieId:(NSInteger)mId
{
    self.movieName=mN;
    self.movieId=mId;
    return self;
}    
**similarly for PlaceName and PersonalityName.**
```

#### My GameCategory.m

```
**//I am stuffing here what do here so that on clicking any of the button the same NIB //opens but with different data.**  
-(IBAction) moviesButtonPressed:(id)sender   
{  
    TheCommonNib *theCommonNib = [[TheCommonNib alloc] initWithNibName:@"TheCommonNib" bundle:nil];  
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:theCommonNib animated:YES];  
    [theCommonNib release];  
}  
-(IBAction) placesButtonPressed:(id)sender   
{  
    TheCommonNib *theCommonNib = [[TheCommonNib alloc] initWithNibName:@"TheCommonNib" bundle:nil];  
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:theCommonNib animated:YES];  
    [theCommonNib release];  
}
```

Please help or guide me.

Comment: where does TheCommonNib have its data? Which data it uses? Please mention which data this nib uses that will make them different.

Answer (score 0):

initialize one flag variable in appdelegate.h and didfinish method in appdelegate.m..and change that value in button pressed event (if button1 pressed,flag value will be 1 or button2 pressed,flag value will be 2,and compare that value in Nib view controller viewWillAppear method,for example through if condition...